# Cannot find name 'XLSX' when adding test.ts file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have added xlsx.full.min.js file.

here is my code

```
var workbook =  XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
var sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
var excelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
```

Comment: You show all but the important parts.. "I have added xlsx.full.min.js file." Show us how. + how do you import the library in the current file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the `XLSX` module using `npm install xlsx` then you have to intialize `XLSX` variable on top of your code `if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');`. Check the library details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Answer (score 7):

For typescript, you have to install `@types/xlsx` by `npm install @types/xlsx --save`.

Import it this way:

`import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

this is [issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/525) on their site.